# Proving that Coefficients of Homogeneous Linear Differential Equations have to be constant if $f^{\prime}$ and $f$ are solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be differentiable functions such that for each solution $f$ of the homogeneous linear differential equation
> $$
> y^{\prime \prime}+a_1 y^{\prime}+a_0 y=0
> $$
> also $f^{\prime}$ is a solution. Then $a_0$ and $a_1$ are constant.

Assuming $f$ is a solution, then
$$
f^{\prime \prime}+a_1 f^{\prime}+a_0 f=0
$$
and
$$
(f^{\prime})^{\prime \prime}+a_1 (f^{\prime})^{\prime}+a_0 (f^{\prime})=f^{\prime \prime}+a_1 f^{\prime \prime}+a_0 f^{\prime}=0.
$$
Hence we have got
$$
f^{\prime\prime \prime}+(a_1-1)f^{\prime\prime}+(a_0-a_1)f^{\prime}-a_0f=0.
$$
and
$$
f^{\prime\prime \prime}+a_1(f^{\prime\prime}-f^{\prime})+a_0(f^\prime-f)=0.
$$
But I do not know how this can be helpful. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a different idea but I can not draw any conclusion. Since $f$ and $f'$ are both solution of the above equation, so we have $$f''+a_1 f'+a_0 f = 0.$$ Suppose that $a_1,a_0$ are not constant i.e., functions of $x$, further assume differentiable w.r.t. $x$. Then differentiation the last equation we get $$a_1'f'+a_0'f=0,$$ where we have used $f''$ is also a solution. But from here I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_0,a_1 :I \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on the interval $I$. Fix any $x_0\in I$ and let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the solution of the initial value problems
$$
y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0, \quad y(x_0)=0, y'(x_0)=1 
$$
and
$$
y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0, \quad y(x_0)=1, y'(x_0)=0, 
$$
respectively. Since $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ are solutions of $y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0$ we get (as observed by Sujit Bhattacharyya)
$$
a_1'(x)f_k'(x)+a_0'(x)f_k(x)=0 \quad (x \in I, k=1,2).
$$
Inserting $x=x_0$ leads to
$$
0=a_1'(x_0)f_1'(x_0)+a_0'(x_0)f_1(x_0)= a_1'(x_0), \quad 0=a_1'(x_0)f_2'(x_0)+a_0'(x_0)f_2(x_0)= a_0'(x_0).
$$
Since $x_0\in I$ was arbitrary we have $a_0'=a_1'=0$ on $I$.